# Wordpress br in content problem

Tags: wp-admin, content

I have this irritating problem with a post in Wordpress (see the url below).

http://www.bytewire.co.uk/services/website-design-essex/

You'll notice the second lower case bold heading (Why Bytewire for website design essex?) is pushed down from the adjacent picture by a br which Wordpress seems to be silently inserting.

I can't seem to work out how to get rid of it or where the hell it's coming from.

Anyone solved this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to the HTML editor and you'll be able to see all of your page markup.  You likely have an unclosed tag or extra line return somewhere in the content, so the visual editor adds additional markup to clean that up.

Comment: Always use HTML editor, it's actually appearing due to a shorttag I think, but theres nothing in the short tag generating the space. Weird.

Comment: Which shorttag?  Maybe update your question to show us the markup that's being used ...